# Change Angular7 decimal formatting globally

Tags: angular, formatting, angular7

How to change angular7 project's decimal formatting? I've researched but I'm just finding solutions for small scopes and for sure there's a way to change locale (i supose is related with it) to take the region formatting and set it as the default for the entire project.

To be more concise i need to swap comma for dot where decimal part comes after comma:
18,245.23€  --> 18.245,23€

printed by: `<span>{{totalPricing | number:'1.0-2'}}€<span>`

Does someone know how??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to not use customize `Date` and `Currency` typed variable formats,

You should define your `LOCALE_ID` which means that you don't need to use custom format for your `Date` or `Currency`  (or currency, time etc.) variables. Add this to your top root module.ts,

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEs from '@angular/common/locales/es';
registerLocaleData(localeEs, 'es');
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
  ],
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es' }]
})
```

Source: https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID#description

**Update:** 
[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3h6zsp-sdknuk) is working stackblitz example.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. It looks the right way to fix my problem, but even setting the `LOCALE_ID` as `'es`' for Spain as you suggested is still not working. Not sure if I'm missing anything...

Comment: I think only 'es' is not enough. Let me check right key for you.

Comment: I've found it in [Angular's package repository files](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/locales) as oficial documentation of i18n suggests... Anyway thanks because I'm probably wrong

Comment: @Jordi Pleae sheck this part: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-currency-pipe-formatting-currency-in-angular/#step-5

Comment: @Jordi is it working? I'm about to produce a stackblitz repo for you.

Comment: I'm getting the same date format whether I set locale to `en-US`or `es-ES`. I guess it would have be different.

Comment: Did you checked main.ts, lines between 15-18 ?

Comment: Omg so sorry, I were missing those lines. Thank you a lot, I really appreciate it!!!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `pipe` for formatting currency

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'currencyFormat'
})
export class CurrencyFormat {
    transform(value: number,
        currencySign: string = '€ ',
        decimalLength: number = 2, 
        chunkDelimiter: string = '.', 
        decimalDelimiter:string = ',',
        chunkLength: number = 3): string {

        value /= 100;

        let result = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + chunkLength + '})+' + (decimalLength > 0 ? '\\D' : '$') + ')';
        let num = value.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~decimalLength));

        return (decimalDelimiter ? num.replace('.', decimalDelimiter) : num).replace(new RegExp(result, 'g'), '$&' + chunkDelimiter) + currencySign;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-currency-pipe-format

Comment: I think I prefer using the default pipe for formatting but well configured. If there isn't any alternative i'll give a try on it. Thanks!